# Driver update following graphic card replacement

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

My previous graphic card died so I bought new one. Now I should do software installation, but my CD drive is not working.

I play lot of games, what will happen if I continue playing games without software installation? Will my new graphic card die?

My new graphic card is NVidia GT 730. I use Windows 7. My previous graphic card was NVidia ZOTAC GeForce 8800GTS.

Comment: I m sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Take a loook: http://www.geforce.com/drivers - here you should get the driver

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can also download the driver from the internet so you don't need CD reader to install it (or ask somebody with working driver to copy it for you).

> Will my new graphic card die or some others components?

I don't think missing driver would influence it's lifespan; more likely you'll have reduced functionality.

Comment: You can find the drivers at the [Geforce website](http://www.geforce.com/drivers).

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen if I continue playing games without software
>   installation.

Any application that requires DirectX or OpenGL will simply not function.  In the specific examples you provide those applications will not even run.

> Will my new graphic card die or some others components?

No;  The hardware will function just fine without the drivers.  It is the software that will not function.  I strongly suggest you install the drivers for your new hardware if the applications require DirectX and OpenGL.

Just download the [355.82 - WHQL - GeForce Game Ready Driver](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/90494) for the card from [Nvidia](http://www.geforce.com/drivers).

Answer (score 1):

1. Please update the title of your case, it is really not enough information.
2. No, if you can play, there are drivers. It would be preferable to use the most updated drivers. Those can be found on NVidias website. You can also download NVidia Experience from there. This would be a program that keeps you informed of new drivers, downloads them for you and installs them. Also it has a few more features for gamers, like setting up your games with the right graphic settings, which usually is a quick way to get started before you get into the game.

But to say the answer more clearly. You won't damage your graphic card by using standard driver, yet, you may be unable to use the complete power of your graphic card